# Jquery form json and return json

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

**I create this little script for using function send forms , i create using function because i haver more of one form in the same page :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send_contacter(idcc)
{

$('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo $phpValidate;?>',
type: 'POST',
data : $('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).serialize(),
success: function(data) {


if (data.fields_empty=="bad")
{
alert('all done');
}

}
});


});

}
</script>


<form id="contact-form-widget-<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>" class="contact-form-widget" method="post" action="" onsubmit="send_contacter('<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>');return false;">
<input class="contact_rapid_boton" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

The target page show this code for read by json :

```
<?php
print '{"fields_empty":"bad"}';
?>
```

I have 2 problems with this :

1 ) I need give double click for works the form

2 ) No works return of json and no launch the alert of javascript

Thank´s for the help , Regards all people here :)

Comment: Check your browser console for the errors.

Comment: In firefox where the console for errors ?

Comment: You need to check for the add-ons in you browser check for `firebug`

Comment: Use firebug to see errors, in Chrome press F12

Comment: No show me errors but continue these problems .....

Comment: Please do observer whether the page is submitted/refreshed with your first click.

And please do add,

data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);

right below the line "success: function(data) {" in your code, and observe whether the alert pops-up.

And I do agree with the other guys. Do not forget to use "firebug" when you are dealing with javascripts and ajax stuff ;D

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I don't understand your question correctly, Is the Response's content-type JSON and you want to read that? why write

```
data.fields_empty=="bad"
```

Shouldn't it be either

```
 data.d=="bad"
```

or

```
data=="bad"
```

Comment: when launch the form this form go other page and in this page show this : print '{"fields_empty":"bad"}'; , and with json must detect into the script if (data.fields_empty=="bad") , but no works ..... Regards !

Comment: try removing the condition and alert the data alone [alert(data);] and see what is shows?

Comment: can you tell me your response code? I am not a php person but instead of having the response "bad" yours has "fields_empty:bad"! put the condition if(data=="fields_empty:bad"), that ought to fire that alert

Answer (score 0):

Just remove/delete `"$('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).on('submit', function(e) {"` event handler from your script. You have already called the same onsubmit event within the  HTML element as

```
onsubmit="send_contacter('<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>');return false;"
```

After deleting this `"$('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).on('submit', function(e) {"` part (of course with the relevant "});" part at the end), this works fine.

Your code the should be,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send_contacter(idcc)
{

$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo $phpValidate;?>',
type: 'POST',
data : $('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).serialize(),
success: function(data) {


if (data.fields_empty=="bad")
{
alert('all done');
}

}
});

}
</script>


<form id="contact-form-widget-<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>" class="contact-form-widget" method="post" action="" onsubmit="send_contacter('<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>');return false;">
<input class="contact_rapid_boton" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

If that json reading issue was still there, add

```
data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

below this line of your code

```
success: function(data) {
```

Thanks.